# Float to Double conversion for android

Tags: java, android, floating-point, double, fft

OK, so this should be simple... But I still can't figure it out. I am writing a program in java for Android to take the fft of a float array. On the complex frequency spectrum returned I extract the real and imaginary components so I can calculate some parameters such as magnitude and phase. The problem is the libgdx fft transform I am using uses float, however most of the Math class operations use double. So that means I need to convert float to double.
It seems to work fine on the Real component of the fft, however with the imaginary I get precision errors, or rather I get for one frequency bin I get an imaginary float value of 45.188522 however, when I convert to double it changes to -45.188522.

```
   fft.forward(array);
   fft_cpx=fft.getSpectrum();
   tmpi = fft.getImaginaryPart();
   tmpr = fft.getRealPart();
   for(int i=0;i<array.length/2;i++)
   {
       real[i] = (double) tmpr[i];
       imag[i] = (double) tmpi[i];  // THIS CONVERSION
       mag[i] = (float)Math.sqrt((real[i]*real[i]) + (imag[i]*imag[i]));
       phase[i] = (float) ((float) Math.atan2(imag[i], real[i]));
   }
```

I am aware and have tried the android FloatMath class, however there is no atan2 implemented so I am forced to convert to double regardless.

I have also tried a few different conversions like:

```
 imag[i] = tmpi[i];
 imag[i] = Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(tmpi[i])); // Of course you loose accuracy
```

But all still return a -45.18852 instead of 45.18852

^^^^^ ORIGINAL ^^^^^^

More Detail:

Below is my src code and usage for those interested.

Ok, I am using Ubuntu 10.10 with eclipse JDK, Version: Helios Service Release 2
Android SDK: The latest r10 from [android developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).
I am compiling for android 1.6, API level 4. 
I am using libgdx for the fft you can get it here, [Libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Building) and ensure you add the gdx.jar to your libs and added to your build path libraries. If you create a new project either with the same or new activity for android 1.6, set up a AVD, the one I have set up has the following support (included for completeness) :

```
SD Card yes
Accellerometer yes
DPas Support yes
Abstracted LCD Density 240
Audio Playback Support yes 
Max VM Application heap size 24
camera support no
Touch Screen support yes
```

Here is my src code:

```
package com.spec.example;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.analysis.FFT;
import java.lang.String;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class spectrogram extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
float[] array = {1, 6, 1, 4, 5, 0, 8, 7, 8, 6, 1,0, 5 ,6, 1,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
float[] array_hat,res=new float[array.length/2];
float[] fft_cpx,tmpr,tmpi,mod_spec =new float[array.length/2];
float[] real_mod = new float[array.length], imag_mod = new float[array.length];
double[] real = new double[array.length], imag= new double[array.length];
double[] mag = new double[array.length] ,phase = new double[array.length];
int n;
float tmp_val;
String strings;
FFT fft = new FFT(32, 8000);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);

   fft.forward(array);
   fft_cpx=fft.getSpectrum();
   tmpi = fft.getImaginaryPart();
   tmpr = fft.getRealPart();
   for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
   {
       real[i] = (double) tmpr[i];   // This works well
       imag[i] = (double) tmpi[i];  // However this is creates a problem
       //mag[i] = FloatMath.sqrt((tmpr[i]*tmpr[i]) + (tmpi[i]*tmpi[i]));   //using FloatMath android class (works fine)
       mag[i] = Math.sqrt((real[i]*real[i]) + (imag[i]*imag[i]));
       phase[i]=Math.atan2(imag[i],real[i]);

       /****Reconstruction****/        
       real_mod[i] = (float) (mag[i] * Math.cos(phase[i]));
       imag_mod[i] = (float) (mag[i] * Math.sin(phase[i]));

   }

   fft.inverse(real_mod,tmpi,res);// inverse fft to reconstruct original array if input = output It works as it is, however it is using the input imaginary, not imag_mod
   strings=String.valueOf(tmpi[1]); // Just printing the second imaginary element Calculated using: |X|e^(j*phaseofX) = |X|(cos(X) + jsin(X))
   //strings=String.valueOf(imag_mod[1]); // Just printing the second imaginary element (Original returned from fft.getImaginary())
    //this ^^ is the one which returns a -ve (Uncomment to test)
   tv.setText(strings);
   setContentView(tv);

    }
  }
```

I am new to android development and java, so please be patient with me if the answer seems obvious or my syntax seems odd. Hopefully someone work it out...

Comment: you might want to rephrase "writing a basic program in java"... Basic is another (unrelated, and widely known, if not used) programming language... The faux pas of a noob. No harm. ;-)

Comment: Could you PLEASE post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which reproduces this behaviour? Also, what's your JDK/SDK version and vendor, O/S, and processor? Forgive me, but I just can't bring myself believe it. If Java's automatic widdening: `double myDoubleValue = myFloatValue` is so completely broken in such an obvious way then (forgive me) I seriously doubt you'd be the first to discover it. So what's your environment, and can we reproduce it?

Comment: Ok, I'll put together a SSCCE for those that are interested. With as much detail as I can. Bear with me. Thanks

Comment: Src code is supplied now, let me know if you want more info if this isn't enough to test it out.

Comment: I just want to make a note, this is not the answer to why my float to double conversions result in a negative number. But the above code still works for calculating the fft of a 16 element array padded with array.length zeros, and this problem doesn't really affect the performance or accuracy of my code.

Comment: Are you sure `tmpi[i]` and `(double) tmpi[i]` do indeed differ that absurdly? How do you test that?

Comment: It seems some devices have problems with conversions... I ran into something very strange where a load/store of a double var gets messed up, but only on specific devices and only when compiled with Proguard obfuscation on using the JVM class compiler. Using the Eclipse class compiler or running the same code on most other Android devices works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to try `Double.parseDouble(new String(tmpr[i]))` instead of the implicit cast: it SHOULDN'T make a difference, but I've seen strange things like that with floats.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited it for that reason.. I assume you mean:

Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(tmpi[i]));

Comment: that kind of thing should not be necessary.  For a start, it is a very expensive way to convert from `float` to `double`.  Please provide a concrete example (with actual code if possible) where this was supposedly necessary.

Comment: Yeah I am in the process of providing more code, I am not using the method stated above. But either way it still returns a negative. Editing original post now to add usable code. Thanks

Comment: This wasn't the solution, I have provided example code above :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find the problem is this line:

```
float[] fft_cpx,tmpr,tmpi,mod_spec = new float[array.length/2];
```

I think you are only instantiating one array, if you replace it with:

```
float[] fft_cpx = new float[array.length/2];
float[] tmpr = new float[array.length/2];
float[] tmpi = new float[array.length/2];
float[] mod_spec = new float[array.length/2];
```

Thereby creating some *separate* objects, you will find that tmpi and img match.

Answer (score 1):

@digiphd,

**This isn't an answer...** it's my humble attempt at a proof that there's nothing wrong with the Java environments widenning conversion from float to double, or the narrowing conversion from double to float.

Would you please run this test (or equivalent) in your environment?

Other than that, the only thing I can suggest is DOUBLE CHECK your variable declarations, and follow the standard of declaring each variable on its own line... and initialise-as-you-declare each variable, which has the side-effect of moving each variable "down" into it's smallest-possible-scope; This is generally regarded as a "good thing", because it minimises opportunity for a variable to be accidentally used/modified somewhere-else unintentionally. This goes TRIPLE for "temporary" variables!!!

**"PROOF" that float ?ALLWAYS? widens to an EQUIVALENT double**

```
package forums;

import java.util.Random;

public class FunkyDouble
{
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
  private static final int HOW_MANY = 100*1000*1000;
  private final static double EPSILON = 0.0000001; // 1/10^7

  public static void main(String... args) 
  {
    double d;
    float f;

    for (int i=0; i<HOW_MANY; i++) {
      d = randomDouble();
      f = (float) d;
      if ( Math.abs(d - f) > EPSILON ) {
        System.out.println("FunkyDouble A: Math.abs("+d+" - "+f+") = "+Math.abs(d - f));
      }

      f = randomFloat();
      d = f;
      if ( Math.abs(f - d) > EPSILON ) {
        System.out.println("FunkyDouble B: Math.abs("+f+" - "+d+") = "+Math.abs(f - d));
      }
    }
  }

  private static double randomDouble() {
    return RANDOM.nextDouble() * (RANDOM.nextBoolean() ? -1.0D : 1.0D);
  }

  private static float randomFloat() {
    return RANDOM.nextFloat() * (RANDOM.nextBoolean() ? -1.0F : 1.0F);
  }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
C:\Java\home\src\forums>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\java.exe" -Xms4m -Xmx256m -enableassertions -cp c:\java\home\src;C:\Java\home\classes; forums.FunkyDouble
Press any key to continue . . .
```

IE: None, as expected.

Comment: The desktop Java VM has (more or less) nothing todo with dalvik running the code in the problem.

Comment: @Stephan: Huh? Would you care to elaborate on that, please? As I understand things, the problem is: `doubles[i] = (double) floats[i];` produces a double-value such that (float)doubles[i] approximately equals floats[i]***-1**... or do you mean that you think this a problem in the Andriod device (presumably a mobile phone) as apposed to the desktop development environment? In which case you might be onto something.

Comment: The Java VM on the desktop is something different than the dalvik VM on Android. Although they seem to run the same code, they are different pieces of software (that's what the Google vs Oracle lawsuit is about, I guess). Most obvious, dalvik runs files in the DEX format and not the bytecode compiled from the java compiler (dx is the tool which converts the one into the other). [The wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software) gives a first hint on the differences.

Comment: So, if there would be a problem in the dalvik VM regarding casting floats to doubles (which I highly doubt, but anyway), you could not proove the contrary by using the desktop VM. So your test is not wrong per se, but running it on the Java VM does not yield meaningful results, if we were up to chasing a bug in the dalvik VM. My first comment might have been a bit harsh, though.